# Convert Float to String in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, typeerror

I have a dataframe with the following dtypes.

```
> df.dtypes
    Col1         float64
    Col2          object
    dtype: object
```

When I do the following:

```py
df['Col3']  = df['Col2'].apply(lambda s: len(s) >= 2  and s[0].isalpha())
```

I get:

```
TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()
```

I believe if I convert "object" to "String", I will get to do what I want. However, when I do the following:

```py
df['Col2'] = df['Col2'].astype(str)
```

the dtype of `Col2` doesn't change. I am a little confused with datatype "object" in Pandas. What exactly is "object"?

More info: This is how `Col2` looks like:

```
               Col2
1                F5
2               K3V
3                B9
4               F0V
5             G8III
6              M0V:
7                G0
8      M6e-M8.5e Tc
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If a column contains string or is treated as string, it will have a `dtype` of `object` (but not necessarily true backward -- more below). Here is a simple example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'SpT': ['string1', 'string2', 'string3'],
                   'num': ['0.1', '0.2', '0.3'],
                   'strange': ['0.1', '0.2', 0.3]})
print df.dtypes
#SpT        object
#num        object
#strange    object
#dtype: object
```

If a column contains only strings, we can apply `len` on it like what you did should work fine:

```
print df['num'].apply(lambda x: len(x))
#0    3
#1    3
#2    3
```

However, a `dtype` of object does not means it only contains strings. For example, the column `strange` contains objects with mixed types -- and some `str` and a `float`. Applying the function `len` will raise an error similar to what you have seen:

```
print df['strange'].apply(lambda x: len(x))
# TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()
```

Thus, the problem could be that you have not properly converted the column to string, and the column still contains mixed object types.

Continuing the above example, let us convert `strange` to strings and check if `apply` works:

```
df['strange'] = df['strange'].astype(str)
print df['strange'].apply(lambda x: len(x))
#0    3
#1    3
#2    3
```

(There is a suspicious discrepancy between `df_cleaned` and `df_clean` there in your question, is it a typo or a mistake in the code that causes the problem?)

Answer (score 1):

###### "Hidden" nulls

If the column dtype is `object`, `TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()` often occurs if the column contains NaN. Check if that's the case by calling

```py
df['Col2'].isna().any()
```

If it returns `True`, then there's NaN and you probably need to handle that.

###### Vectorized `str.` methods

If null handling is not important, you can also call vectorized `str.len()`, `str.isdigit()` etc. methods. For example, the code in the OP can be written as:

```py
df['Col3'] = df['Col2'].str.len().ge(2) & df['Col2'].str[0].str.isalpha()
```

to get the desired output without errors.

###### 'string' dtype

Since pandas 1.0, there's a new `'string'` dtype where you can keep a Nullable integer dtype after casting a column into a `'string'` dtype. For example, if you want to convert floats to strings without decimals, yet the column contains NaN values that you want to keep as null, you can use `'string'` dtype.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Col1': [1.2, 3.4, 5.5, float('nan')]
})

df['Col1'] = df['Col1'].astype('string').str.split('.').str[0]
```

returns

```
0       1
1       3
2       5
3    <NA>
Name: Col1, dtype: object
```

where `<NA>` is a Nullable integer that you can drop with `dropna()` while `df['Col1'].astype(str)` casts NaNs into strings.